# How to run a command with a hidden password

Tags: shell-script, curl

I need to run a curl command that accesses a website that another person has the password to.

e.g.
`curl --basic --user myfriendsname:friendspassword http://www.updateinfo.com`

I need a way where I can launch this script without being able to see my friend's password.

Answer (score 5):

From `man curl`:

```
-u, --user <user:password>
  ...
  If you just give the user name (without entering a colon) curl will prompt
  for a password.
  ...
```

Just pass them the keyboard (or a `screen`/`tmux` share) and have them type it in.

Comment: Obviously, the problem with the `--user` parameter is that the password can be intercepted with `ps` while the process is running, if passed on the command line. Prompting is a cool solution if we're not trying to automate. :)

Comment: I guess input redirection would still be possible?  I'm confused by redirecting unusual fd's too, but I think it should be possible.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, that's helpful if my friend is in the room but the whole point of scripting it is to automate it.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison Can you please update your question then. Without information we can't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3):

If you had checked `man curl` or [the curl FAQ](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#How_do_I_keep_user_names_and_pas), you would know that `curl` has the `--config`/`-K` parameter to:

> Specify which config file to read curl arguments from. The config file
>   is a text file in which  command  line  arguments  can  be written
>   which then will be used as if they were written on the actual command
>   line.
>   ... ([man curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html))

For example, you could store and decrypt the password with `gpg`. The decrypt parameter is `-d`.

## Update: A complete solution step-by-step

Initially I did not provide a complete solution, because that would be *giving you a fish*, when you *learning to fish yourself* is more valuable.

But since you seem really unsure about how to proceed, here's a [quick and dirty script in Python 3.3 to manage the HTTP password secret](https://github.com/guyhughes/curling-with-secrets/blob/master/curling-with-secrets.py).

Just download that script (or clone repo with git), `chmod u+x ./curling-with-secrets.py` then run it with `./curling-with-secrets --help`, and you'll see this:

```
❯ ./curling-with-secrets.py --help
usage: curling-with-secrets.py [-h] [--secretfile [SECRETFILE]] user url

This is curling-with-secrets by Guy Hughes.

positional arguments:
  user                  the username to pass to curl
  url                   the url to pass to curl

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --secretfile [SECRETFILE]
                        specify an alternative secret file
```

The script creates a file, `secret.enc` given by the variable `secretfile`, in its directory by using `openssl` to encrypt the file using the `sha512sum` salted hash of the filepath as the passphrase. This does not provide a high level of security, but it would take a bit of effort for anyone to view the password, whereas storing it in cleartext makes viewing the password accidentially with `cat` or `quicklook` in OS X far too easy. Your friend could harden this by changing the encryption mechanism and the `token()` function, then storing the file in a location that your user account does not have read permissions, but does have execute permissions, and owned by another user and group, supposing you do not have `sudoers` or `root` access to the host.

After the `secretfile` is created, the script runs `curl` with the specified  user authentication and url passed on the command line. These options are passed to `STDIN` to `curl` using the `-K -` option (which reads a configuration file from `STDIN`), formatted as a `curl` configuration file. You can easily extend this to suit your needs following `man curl`.  :)

I am not really much of a Python person, so there's probably some kinks in this script, but it could be a good starting point for you. You should definitely test it throughly.

Here's the full source of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.3

#  Guy Hughes, 2014
#  GNU General Public License Version 3, 29 June 2007

from sys import stdin
from sys import stdout
import os
import argparse
#from sys import os.environ
#from sys import os.access
#from sys import os.mkdirs
#from sys import os.path
import subprocess
import errno
import getpass

def init():
    global args
    global secretfile
    global secretfiledir
    # parse args
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is curling-with-secrets by Guy Hughes.')
    parser.add_argument('--secretfile',nargs='?',help='specify an alternative secret file',type=str)
    parser.add_argument('user', help='the username to pass to curl',type=str)
    parser.add_argument('url', help='the url to pass to curl',type=str)
    args=parser.parse_args()
    #secretfile=os.path.abspath(os.environ.get('XDG_CONFIG_HOME',os.environ.get('HOME') + "/.config") + "/secretcurl/secret.enc")
    if args.secretfile:
        secretfile = os.path.abspath(args.secretfile)
    else:
        secretfile=os.path.abspath('./secret.enc')
        secretfiledir=os.path.dirname(secretfile)

    if check():
        curl()

def check():
    if os.path.isfile(secretfile) and os.access(secretfile, os.R_OK):
        print("I found secretfile at %s. [OK]" % secretfile)
        return True
    else:
        print("I did not find the secretfile at %s. We'll now create it..." % secretfile)
        return createfile()

def token():
    echop=subprocess.Popen(["echo", secretfile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    shap=subprocess.Popen(['sha512sum'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=echop.stdout)
    grepp=subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-Eo','\'^.{40}\''],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=shap.stdout)
    echop.stdout.close()
    shap.stdout.close()
    result=grepp.communicate()[0]
    return result


def createfile():
    # safety check
    if os.path.isfile(secretfile):
        print("FATAL: secretfile exists at %s" % secretfile)
        print("Stopping, to prevent secretfile from being overriden.")
        print("If you wish to overwrite the secretfile, first delete it yourself this run this command again.")
        exit(1)

    print("Creating the secretfile at %s" % secretfile)
    print("Remember: Once the secret file is created, this script"
          " will only be able to decrypt while it is in the same directory and filename."
          "If you ever wish to rename the secretfile, you'd need to modify this script "
          "or recreate the secretfile using this script.")

    print("Checking for directory %s" % secretfiledir)
    if not os.path.exists(secretfiledir):
        sys.stdout.write("Making directories...")
        os.makedirs(secretfiledir, exist_ok=True)
    else:
        print("Parent directories are OK")

    print("Please enter the secret password to be passed to curl:")
    password=getpass.getpass()
    thetoken = token()
    echop=subprocess.Popen(['echo',password],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    opensslp=subprocess.Popen(['openssl', 'enc', '-aes-256-cbc',
                     '-salt', '-a',
                     '-k', thetoken,
                     '-out', secretfile
                     ], stdin=echop.stdout)
    echop.stdout.close()

    del password
    del thetoken

    print("Createfile done.")
    return True

def curl():
    print("Decrypting the password...")
    thetoken=token()
    opensslp=subprocess.Popen(['openssl','enc','-aes-256-cbc','-d', '-a','-k',thetoken,
                                      '-in', secretfile],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    password=opensslp.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
    print(args)
    print(args.url)
    print(password)
    curlconfig="user = " + args.user + "\:" + password  + "\nurl = " + args.url
    curlp=subprocess.Popen(['curl','--basic', '-K', '-'],
                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=False)
    result=curlp.communicate(input=bytes(curlconfig, 'UTF-8'))
    print(result)



    del password



init()
```

Comment: Id like to take your word for it that this idea will work but it's going to take me a while to study the man file on curl and the curl FAQ and then do trial and error testing until i figure out a line of code that will work for my situation. Then if i did intact find the solution all the work i put into this research would prompt me to write an answer that someone could actually plugin and use and post it here myself .... 0_o

Comment: @JoshuaRobison I updated my answer with a full solution. ☺